# Error after clear the cache manually [symfony2]

Tags: php, symfony, caching

I couldn't clear the cache with the command-line , so have decided to clear the cache manually, but when I refresh the page I have the following error:

> RuntimeException in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Debug\DebugClassLoader.php
>   line 258: The autoloader expected class "Http\Message\Formatter" to be
>   defined in file
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\vendor\composer/../php-http/message/src\Formatter.php".
>   The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or
>   namespace probably has a typo.

I have tried to run this command php `app/console cache:warmup` but still having the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I just fix this issue by removing these two bundle in my composer.json :

```
  "egeloen/google-map-bundle": "dev-master",
    "php-http/httplug-bundle": "1.3.0",
```

and I run `composer update`

I think the problem came from php-http/httplug-bundle but I don't know why...